# How do I get and test the state of requests.head in this code?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have the following code:

```
   def verify_pseudo_streaming(self, publishedName, path, start):
        cname = self.get_cname(publishedName)
        params = {'start': start}
        url = 'http://{}{}'.format(cname, path)
        origin_size = int(requests.head(url).headers['Content-Length'])
        start_headers = requests.head(url, params=params).headers
        start_size = int(start_headers['Content-Length'])
        msg = "Start size is not lower than origin size"
        assert start_size < origin_size, msg
```

In my test I have mocked the `requests.head` in my unit test, how do I get the value of `headers` the first and second time when running `requests.head` without really running it ?

**I finally ended up doing the one below which worked ...**

```
class MockHeaders(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def streaming_headers(self, *args, **kwargs):
        start = kwargs.get('params', {})
        self.headers['Content-Length'] = start.get('start', 10)
        stuff = Mock()
        stuff.headers = self.headers
        return stuff

<snip> ... </snip>

    @patch("FrontEnd.requests.head")
    @patch("FrontEnd.FrontEnd.get_cname")
    def test_verify_pseudo_streaming(self, mock_get_cname,mock_head):
        mock_get_cname.return_value = 'hulahoop'
        mock_header = MockHeaders()
        mock_head.side_effect = mock_header.streaming_headers
        mock_head.return_value = mock_header
        try:
            self.fe.verify_pseudo_streaming('publishedName', 'path', 5)
        except AssertionError:
            self.fail("Unexpected Assertion Error")
```

I am just going to keep this open to see if others got other more elegant ideas.

Answer (score 0):

you can mock \ monkeypatch only this method

```
requests.sessions.Session.send
```

this is what requests use to send the request, so if you change that to do nothing
it will not send the request

```
def x(*args, **kwarg):
    pass
requests.sessions.Session.send = x
```

Answer (score 0):

I would mock out requests like this:

```
class FakeHeaders(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.headers = {'Content-Length': 1}

  def inc_headers():
    self.headers['Content-Length'] += 1

def testVerifyPsuedoStreaming(self):
  fake_header = FakeHeader()
  with mock.patch.object(
      request, 'head', side_effect=fake_header.inc_headers,
      return_value=fake_header) as mock_head:
    ...
```